# What exactly happen when we reference a library as additional dependency in a C++ project using VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

when we want to use a static library (*.lib) file we reference it in project properties in additional library dependencies portion, what i do want to know is how exactly VS handle this linkage? in other words is there any alternative way to this VS task -linking a library in link step- by piece of code or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#pragma comment(lib, "<library path and name>")
```

Then you don´t need to add your library into project settings

Comment: would you please give me an example? for instance my library name is "actor.lib" and here is it's path: "C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARDALAN_OS1\actor.lib" thanks in advance

Comment: by the way if there is a function in actor.lib namely "somefunc()" how can I use it in my code using your way to link the library?

Comment: For the first question - you just add full path to the lib (Meanining C://Users... ) - But this solution is not very portable. Best is to have lib somewhere in your project

Comment: Second question - If you want to use lib, you need to have header file for it and #include it the ususal way

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what Visual Studio has done, add the reference. Now, using your source control/favorite diff tool, compare the old .vcxproj file to the new one. You should see what changes were made to the .vcxproj, which is the file used to drive the build.

I assume that you are using source control and the .vcxproj is under source control. If not, make a copy of the original .vcxproj somewhere to compare with. (Also, strongly consider using source control. :-] )

Comment: what is source control/favorite diff tool?

Comment: Read that as "your [source control's built in diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) or your favorite [diff tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)."

Comment: yes I read that as you say but is there any tutorial on how to use source control's built in diff?

Comment: That depends on which source control system you are using. A quick search on the Internet should answer that question for you.